# Scala: Convert org.w3c.dom.Document to scala.xml.NodeSeq

Tags: java, xml, dom, scala

Title is pretty self-explanatory. How can I convert an instance of org.w3c.dom.Document to a Scala NodeSeq, to enjoy it's facilitation?

Cheers
Parsa

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  def asXml(dom: org.w3c.dom.Node): Node = {
    val dom2sax = new DOM2SAX(dom)
    val adapter = new NoBindingFactoryAdapter
    dom2sax.setContentHandler(adapter)
    dom2sax.parse()
    return adapter.rootElem
  }
```

Comment: The questions ask for a converter from `org.w3c.dom.Document` to `scala.xml.NodeSeq` but your code take a `org.w3c.dom.Node` as parameter.
—
And having the appropriate `imports` always makes it that little easier.

Comment: I found `scala.xml.parsing.NoBindingFactoryAdapter` but I can't find `DOM2SAX` for less no money. Or better google returns to many results so I don't know which is the one.
—
Please: In example code fully qualified class names. Thanks

Comment: I guess you meant `org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.DOM2SAX` which not only means one has to know the package name. One also have to find out which external library it is in.
—
So one left: How to convert an `org.w3c.dom.Document` into a `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

Comment: @Martin: Since `org.w3c.dom.Document` extends `org.w3c.dom.Node`, you can pass your `Document` into this method.

Answer (score 6):

IttayD's answer is good for all w3c XMLs - except dom4j w3c compatible xmls. the following works for all w3c types:

```
def asXml(dom: _root_.org.w3c.dom.Node): Node = {
    val source = new DOMSource(dom)
    val adapter = new NoBindingFactoryAdapter
    val saxResult = new SAXResult(adapter)
    val transformerFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance()
    val transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer()
    transformer.transform(source, saxResult)
    adapter.rootElem
  }
```

Comment: I say the same as to IttayD: Please: In example code fully qualified class names. Thanks. And to bad that `javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource` is not available on Android API <8. But I guess that is not your problem.

Comment: Where does your `transformerFactory` come from?

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet there's a val transformerFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance() defined in the containing object.

Comment: Sadly I end up with an error when trying this: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.w3c.tidy.DOMDocumentImpl.getXmlStandalone()Z

Comment: This works for SOAP response from Apache CXF jax-ws generated SOAP client. It is even more convenient if the above is an `implicit` function in scope in the service tier. All objects returned above that are scala.xml.Node.

Comment: another benefit of this solution compared to the accepted one is avoiding using apache xalan (potentially through a transitive dependency)

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this code a while back to go in the other direction, from a Scala node to a Dom4J Node.  It shows the basic idea of recursing over a tree and should be easy enough to adapt:

```
implicit def scalaToDom4j(n : Node) : DElem = {

  def inner(n : Node) : Option[DNode] = {
    n match {
      case e : Elem =>
        val elem = DocumentHelper.createElement(e.label)
        for(c <- e.child) yield inner(c) collect {
          case Some(child) => elem.add(child)
        }
        Some(elem)
        //as Scala's xml is type-aware, text might not actually be a Text node,
        //but an Atom of some other type
      case t : Atom[_] =>
        Some(DocumentHelper.createText(t.data.toString))
      case x => None
    }
  }

  //Attempt the conversion. Throw an exception if something has gone badly wrong
  //inner returns an Option[DNode], but the expected top-level type is a DElem
  // (which is a subclass of DNode)
  //so we also validate this.
  inner(trim(n)) map (_.asInstanceOf[DElem]) getOrElse (error("xml failed"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recursive pattern-matching code similiar to the scalaToDom4j(n) function above, only in the Saxon XdmNode to Scala Node direction up at: 
https://github.com/LeifW/MusicPath/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/musicpath/saxon2scala/Saxon2Scala.scala

Currently it just makes Text, Element, and non-namespaced Attribute nodes, but it should be easy to generalize / finish.